# Run time error "1004" in vba code

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have run time error for this code:

```
TextBox8 = Worksheets("listofbuyer").Range("B" & ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is your combo box either has:-
1. No selection made yet
2. Is set to a value that does not match one of the entries in the list (properties to achieve this are `Style = fmStyleDropDownCombo` and `MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone`

Either way, you will find `ComboBox1.ListIndex` is equal to -1, thus resulting in a `Range` specified as `B0`.